# Why doesn't QGIS dissolve work properly for some datasets?

Tags: qgis, dissolve

I am used to work with ArcGIS and now I started to explore QGIS more. I have problem with dissolve function. I have administrative borders and I would like to dissolve them into higher administrative areas. When I process dissolve according to common attribute NUTS3 - I get strange results - see pic.

It works fine in ArcMap 10.2.2. can you tell me, what do I do wrong in QGIS?

[image: dissolve settings]

[image: dissolve results]

[image: dissolve with attribute table]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try using the **v.clean** function from the *GRASS* plugin (you can also access this from the *Processing* plugin if installed). This tends to remove errors (if any) from your layer then try running **Dissolve** again.

You can also use the **Check Geometry Validity** via *Vector* > *Geometry Tools* > *Check Geometry Validity* to see if there are any errors in your layer.

Answer (score 4):

I Spent quite a while struggling with a similar problem in QGIS as the dissolve function was leaving two groups out of the dissolve by attribute. It turned out to be dirty geometry in the digitised layer being grouped. A quick run through with the Topology checker revealed some simple errors once fixed it ran like a dream.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and it turns out the issue was caused by holes in the geometry. I successfully dissolved the geometries by first applying the *Delete holes* algorithm that you can find under *Processing > Toolbox > QGIS geoalgorithms > Vector geometry tools > Delete holes*.

Answer (score 2):

Try the SAGA Polygon Dissolve (by attribute) in QGIS 3.10.9. Works like a charm !!

Answer (score 1):

I constantly suffer dissolving issues. Problem was most of the times topology errors. You can detect them as described above with `vector > Geometry Tools > Check Geometry Validity` . Often this are ring intersections. You can try using the different tools to fix geometry errors which you can find searching for "fix" or "clean" in the QGIS toolbox searchbar. However, I found that often it is easiest and fastest to just buffer your layer a little (See also [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/265661/fixing-polygon-self-intersection-in-qgis).) and then apply any dissolve algorithm contained in the QGIS tools. Self intersections are often not fixed with the other tools above.

If you have slivers after dissolving as described above you might also try to buffer with a zero distance or very small distance after applying dissolve. This also reduces the slivers.

Last but not least you can also delete them manually when going into the editing mode in the layer.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add an additional solution which worked for me.

My situation was that there was a polygon which had two edges intersecting. Normal dissolve tool did not resolve this (as in, remove the adjacent line), nor did the Geometry validator pickup anything wrong.

What did work, was using the **GRASS Dissolve tool**, as this has a tolerance setting available to the end user.

So v.dissolve and set the snap tolerance to (in my instance 0.01) and this dissolved the poly