# Changing vertex order for polygons in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, vertices, order, self-intersection

I have this intersection of a polygon, see image below

[image: example]

I would like to redraw the lines so they don't cross each other.

So, in the end, I would like to have a polygon without self-intersecting parts. How can I accomplish this?

[image: desired_output]

Comment: Have you seen this article [Fixing polygon self-intersection in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/265661/)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `vertex tool` is what you are looking for. Select the polygon layer you like to change and go into edit mode. Then choose the vertex tool and click on the vertex you like to edit. You can either move it or delete it. By clicking on the `+` between two vertices (while hovering with your mouse) you are able to create a new vertex.

[image]

By the way: It works the same way for line layers.

Comment: That works for deleting the vertex but then I don't have the vertex left to redraw a line between them. I wounder if it is possible to just delete the line between the two points or do  I need to convert the polygon to a line first and then edit it and make it back to a polygon? 
Thanks

Comment: You don't need to convert it. As I said, to redraw a vertex click on the little `+` that appears between two vertices when hovering a vertex. You can also move a vertex by clicking on it and moving it around.

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstand you. I added a picture. Like the picture shows I need these red vertex to stay there so I can draw the polygon so it correspond to the red lines. If i move the vertex over to the other side, then I don't know where to place the other one, because there is nothing to snap to.

Comment: If you have nothing to snap to, you could place the vertex roughly where it was before. Or you create another vertex, place it above an existing one, move the existing vertex over the other vertex and delete this one. Trick around a little.

Comment: Oh, okej. No easier way. I thought about to copy the whole layer and just snap to the background layer. Thanks for the tips!

Comment: Sure, that would also work! Always glad if I can help. If this answered your question, please click the checkmark to mark this question as answered.